# Get content of a JSP and send it via email in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, jakarta-mail

I have a JSP file where the content of it needs to be sent by an email.
Want to collect the content of the file and replace some placeholders, put it in the body of the mail (using javax.mail) and send it away.
Is there a way to render the JSP file with passed variables and get its content back?

Comment: The way I got it working is to get the Path of the file `Paths.get("// path-to-the-file //");`
And then using lines function to get the stream of strings `Files.lines(path)` and collect it in one string `lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to read data from jsp like this:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL yahoo = new URL("http://yourhost.com/index.jsp");
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine, data = "";

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            data += inputLine;
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Then you can send data via email.

Comment: Thanks, I've done the similar way by using Stream of string elements from Java 8 Files class, with the lines() method